# Low bound for the probabilty that every node in a graph has at least one neighbor in a set of nodes from the graph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, probability-limit-theorems

I have been given a question and I dont even know where I should begin:

Given a graph with $n$ nodes where every node has at least $\sqrt{n}$ neighbors,

We build the set $S$ in the following order: for $0.3n$ times we pick each time one node randomly and independently and put it in $S$ (repeatition is possible).

Find a low bound for the probability that for every node in the graph there is at least one neighbor in $S$.

Assume that $n$ is a big number.

I have tried all sort of things but I can't seem to get close to the solution, I thought to use indicators to try and sum the number of different nodes in $S$ and by using the Central limit theorem (n is a big number) to somehow get the answer, but when I started defining the indicators it got messy and I could not define them.

P.s . The way $S$ is built reminded me of a Binomial distribution but i failed there too.

I would appreciate if someone could give me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I_v$ be the indicator of the event that $v$ has no neighbors in $S$. Then
$$E(I_v) \le (1-\sqrt{n}/n)^{3n/10} \le \exp(-3\sqrt{n}/10)\,,$$
since $1-x \le \exp(-x).$
Summing over all vertices in the graph, we find that the probability there is a vertex with no neighbor in $S$ is at most
$$E (\sum_v  I_v) \le n\exp(-3\sqrt{n}/10)\,.$$
Thus  the probability that for every node in the graph there is at least one neighbor in $S$ is at least $1-n\exp(-3\sqrt{n}/10)\,.$